# Maven pulling in an older version of a library

Tags: maven, akka, transitive-dependency

My project has dependency on a jar that depends on akka version **2.5.6**. For some reason my project is pulling in an older version of akka **2.4.16**.

Output of

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true

com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:jar:2.4.16:compile (version managed from 2.5.6)
```

Output of

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose | grep akka

[INFO] |  +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:jar:2.4.16:compile (version managed from 2.5.6)
[INFO] |  +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.11:jar:2.4.16:compile (version managed from 2.5.6)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:jar:2.4.16:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
```

There is **no transitive dependency** on akka anywhere else. Why is this happening?

Comment: Take try "sbt clean" ?

Answer (score 0):

The version number comes from the `<dependencyManagement>`, either from a direct entry, or from a so-called BOM, i.e. as entry of a POM that was imported with `<scope>import</scope>`.